# What do I need to change so that the look of the sidebar (Ubuntu Dock) changes?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm trying to modify the look of my new Ubuntu 18.04 install, but the sidebar (Ubuntu Dock) just doesn't seem to change at all. I've been able to change the look of the apps and the shell (by installing new themes and using tweaks), but none of them seem to affect the sidebar at all - except for icon packs which do affect the icons displayed on the sidebar. However, that only affects the icons, the rest of the siebar looks the same as ever.

Can this part be changed? I'm hoping it can because not all themes work with this black sidebar.

Adapta:
[image]

Flat Remix:
[image]

I am expecting the dock to match the looks of the rest of the desktop. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to download/install to make this happen.

Some information that might help:

- Ubuntu Version: 18.04.3 LTS
- GNOME: 3.28.2

Comment: What exact changes to the dock do you have in mind, e.g. colour, size, transparency or something else? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Dock is actually a fork of the Dash to Dock extension, forked to remove configuration settings. If you want to customize the dock beyond what the Ubuntu developpers want to support, then you may want to disable Ubuntu Dock and install the Gnome Shell extension "Dash to Dock" instead. The "Dash to Dock" settings can be accessed by right-clicking the "All program" icon, or from "Tweaks", or from the Gnome Extensions website.

The "Dash to Dock" settings include a tab "Appearance". There, you can disable that the dock uses your current GNOME theme and customize the dash color and opacity.

Note that, internally, Ubuntu Dock uses the same settings as Dash To Dock. Changes you apply in the Dash to Dock configuration therefore will also affect Ubuntu Dock if you turn off Dash to Dock and turn on Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about that, so this is very helpful.